# When I add a new column to my table, insert start failing with error Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ENROLLED_COURSES` (
  `EmployeeID` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `CourseID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DueDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreationDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `UpdateDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UpdatedBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `KnetUpdateDateUTC` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `OverrideStatusFlag` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `OverrideReason` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsSelfAssigned` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsManagerAssigned` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LPCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Importance` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EmployeeID`,`CourseID`),
  KEY `CourseID-ForeignKey-Constraint` (`CourseID`),
  CONSTRAINT `CourseID-ForeignKey-Constraint` FOREIGN KEY (`CourseID`) REFERENCES `COURSE_CATALOG` (`CourseID`),
  CONSTRAINT `EmployeeID-ForeignKey-Constraint` FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeID`) REFERENCES `EMPLOYEE_DETAILS` (`EmployeeID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Insert Query which start failing:

```
INSERT INTO
    ENROLLED_COURSES (
      EmployeeID,
      CourseID,
      Status,
      DueDate,
      CreationDate,
      CreatedBy,
      IsSelfAssigned,
      IsManagerAssigned,
      LPCount
    )
    VALUES(
    'abcde',
    '186',
    'Assigned',
    '2019-12-16',
     curdate(),
    'LP Assigned',
     0,
     0,
     1
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    UpdatedBy  = IF(Values(DueDate) < IFNULL(DueDate, '9999-12-31'), Values(CreatedBy), UpdatedBy),
    UpdateDate = IF(Values(DueDate) < IFNULL(DueDate, '9999-12-31'), curdate(), UpdateDate),
    DueDate    = IF(Values(DueDate) < IFNULL(DueDate, '9999-12-31'), Values(DueDate), DueDate),
    IsSelfAssigned = Values(IsSelfAssigned),
    IsManagerAssigned = Values(IsManagerAssigned),
    LPCount    = Values(LPCount);
```

Alter query

```
ALTER TABLE ENROLLED_COURSES ADD Importance VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: [works for me](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7EwR6GPENw8ZRRKSBJhiGE/0)

Comment: Are you sure that's the `INSERT` query that's failing? This is the error you'd expect if you leave out the list of column names in the `INSERT`, because it defaults to all the columns.

Comment: Which is why it's generally a bad idea to write `INSERT` queries like that.

Comment: Check triggers.

Comment: Yes insert query is already there in our code. On adding a new column, it start failing. On dropping it, it start working.

Comment: It is very unclear question.

Comment: I don't believe you. Source structure contains the field named `Importance` already, so `ALTER TABLE ...` will fail, DDL will stay unchanged, the query execution will stay unchanged too, error message would not produced.

Answer (score 0):

I trigger defined on the table was the cause of the issue.